# Install4j installation location screen's directory chooser append previous path's last folder name to the browse directory

Tags: install4j

I am using installation location screen for directory selection.

Default installation directory path set to `"c:\Program Files\DEMO"`.

When I choose some different directory using browse button, last folder name of previous installation path gets appended to current selected path.

Like in below case **DEMO** gets appended to `"d:\installer"`.

Previous:

```
c:\Program Files\DEMO
```

Current:

```
d:\installer\DEMO
```

Is this default behavior of `install4j` ?

If yes, how to stop this behavior ? Or I missing some configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the "Installation location" screen, deselect the "Suggest application directory" property to suppress the addition of the short application name to the installation directory.